# Zoomable circle packing, showing a longer text when clicking leaf node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I am quite new to d3.js and i am working with this zoomable circle packing https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535.

when i click the inner node or leaf node you zoom all the way back out. what i want is to zoom even more and then display a text inside the leaf node. i want this text to be longer like a description but the problem is that all the text is on one line.

i have kinda made it look a bit more like i want by putting every leaf node inside another node and then making the leaf node transparent. but i still have the problem that the entire text is only one line.

anyone have som insight?